# Local Variable referenced before assignment even though it is assigned

Tags: python, variables, scope

```
class Trie:
    def __init__(self):
        self.children = [None] * 26
        self.count = 0

def solve(words,k):
    fap=0
    trie = Trie()
    for x in words:
        cur = trie
        for ch in x:
            i = ord(ch) - ord('A')
            if(cur.children[i] is None):
                cur.children[i] = Trie()
            cur = cur.children[i]
        cur.count+=1
    
    def dfs(node,depth=0):
        for c in range (0,26):
            if(node.children[c] is not None):
                dfs(node.children[c],depth+1)
                node.count+=node.children[c].count
        while(node.count>=k):
            fap+=depth
            node.count-=k
    dfs(trie)
    return fap
```

`words` is initialized to `['foo','bar']`
`k` is initialized to 2

The line

```
fap+= depth
```

gives the error:

```
local variable 'fap' referenced before assignment
```

even though `fap` is assigned to 0 in first line of the `solve` function.

Comment: But the DFS function is inside the solve function

Comment: @Ronald The indentation is correct, `dfs` is defined inside `solve`, and called at the end of `solve`.

Comment: My mistake. I removed it and was able to reproduce the error.

Comment: If instead of fap variable  I declare fap as array then this error is not produced .. why so ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line

```
fap+=depth
```

is inside the `dfs` function, not `solve`.

As you assign to `fap` inside `dfs`, it will by default be considered local to `dfs`, hence the error.

If you want to update the `fap` variable from the enclosing scope, the `solve` function, you must declare it `nonlocal`:

```
   def dfs(node,depth=0):
        nonlocal fap
        for c in range (0,26):
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `nonlocal fap` in your `dfs()` function because otherwise you can't access your variable in your inner function

Comment: Because you probably didn't assign to it anymore, but mutated it by appending, so it won't be considered local. The general rule is, if you assign to a variable anywhere in the body of a function, it is considered local to the function, unless you declared it global or nonlocal.

Comment: I had mutated the first element , I was working on the 0th index of the array